# ember 1.12 findAll issue using rest, pod model over json response

Tags: json, rest, ember.js

**I have a Rest adapter right configured and when I try:**

**router.js**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('main.user');
    }
});
```

**I got this:**

> WARNING: Encountered "main.user" in payload, but no model was found
>   for model name "mainUser" (resolved model name using
>   plezure@serializer:-rest:.typeForRoot("main.user"))

**Error while processing route:**

> main.user Assertion Failed: The response from a findAll must be an
>   Array, not undefined Error: Assertion Failed: The response from a
>   findAll must be an Array, not undefined

**My Json return:**

```
{
   "main.user": [
      { "id": "1", "name": "foo" },
      { "id": "2", "name": "bar" }
   ]
}
```

**model.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

My pod are right configured, everything is fine, all works if I change to the find to a non-pod model, like this (model exists at main/):

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('main');
    }
});
```

But with 'main.user' ember is uncapable to deal with json return, using fixtures pod names works well, it's ony happens on json response.

Anyone have any ideia about this kind of issue?

Comment: What is your model name?, and have you try to create a custom adapter?

Comment: My model is inside app/modules/main/user/model.js, as I said, im using a pod structure and it's working fine for template, controller, etc.

I'm using standard RESTadapater.

The problem is when I try to use the pod model name convention with rest (which uses a json call and return), it's broke saying "no model was found for model name mainUser", i think it's happening because when json evals the data try to be inserted at mainUsers model, where in pod structure it's main.user